# Finding last transaction date of set of customers in each year and pull value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have df with 10000 customers and I am trying to find the last transaction date & amount in each year for each customer. With the following I am able to arrive at last date per customer but unable to find it within year.

df[df.groupby('customer').date.transform('max')

Any thoughts on how to find this out

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: add a snippet result of your df

Comment: each calendar year (i.e. for 2020,2019, 2018, etc)? Or every year with first day of data being day 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a column in your dataframe called **TransactionDate** with the transaction dates in datetime format you could do:

```
df['LastTransDateByYear'] = df.groupby(['Customer',df.TransactionDate.dt.year])['TransactionDate'].transform(max)
```

which will add the column to the dataframe with the date that is the last transaction date for a given year.